# How to return a index of values True(bool) that come after a 1( int ) inside a list using python

Tags: python, indexing

I need to do a function in Python to receives 2 arguments an 'item' object and a 'list' list and returns the index of the position in which item occurs in the list.
If item does not occur in the list, the function returns None

When a list contain thea  integer 1 before a boolean True, the function isn't working (test 2).

Example with tests below:

```
def indice(item, lis):
    '''
    (object,list) -> int ou None
    Receives an 'item' object and a 'list' list and returns the
    index of the position in which item occurs in the list.
    If item does not occur in the list, the function returns None
    '''
    for i in lista:
        if i == item:
            return (lista.index(item))
    return None
```

lista  = [1,"hi", 3.14, 7, True]

```
# test 1
if indice("hi",lista) == 1:
    print("Passed the first test! :-)")
else:
    print("Not passed the first test! :-(")

# test 2
if indice(True,lista) == 4:
    print("Passed the second test! :-)")
else:
    print("Not passed the second test! :-(")

# test 3
if indice(False,lista) == None:
    print("Passed the third test! :-)")
else:
    print("Not passed the third test! :-(")
```

Output:

```
Passed the first test! :-)
Nao passed the second test! :-(
Passed the third test! :-)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW: `index()` is not good idea because it gives index for first item. If you will have the same item two times (or more) and you will need index for second item (or next item) then it gives you index for first item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is arising because in python `1` is equivalent to `True` and `0` is equivalent to `False`. So in your code when during the first iteration ie element at index 0, it checks `1== True` which result in `True` statement and it then proceeds to return part where it searches the index from the first element ie `index 0`, at index 0 it finds out that item matches the condition so it `returns 0`

little modification to your code

```
def indice(item, lis):
    '''
    (object,list) -> int ou None
    Receives an 'item' object and a 'list' list and returns the
    index of the position in which item occurs in the list.
    If item does not occur in the list, the function returns None
    '''

    for i,v in enumerate(lis):
 
        if v == item and type(v) == type(item):
            return i
    return None

lista = [1,"hi", 3.14, 7, True]
x = indice(True, lista)

print(x) # output 4
```

use `enumerate` to iterate through the list and keep index and value together so you don't need to use `list.index` the value which will result in the false index as in this case.

you need to keep check the type of item in list with the item you are looking for
as `1==True` is `True` but the type of both of them is different, one being `int` type other being `bool` type. so also comparing `type` of the object will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @sahasrara62. I tried use enumerate but not as a index.

Comment: @EduardoRocha Welcome, it's just a modified code on top of your code which i would try out. whole point was to understand the concept and why your code is behaving like that. hope you got that point